# Winjs background downloader does not start

Tags: windows, cordova, winjs

in my windows cordova application I try to download a file, with the following function (I just copied the code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx)):

```
var uri = Windows.Foundation.Uri(contentUrl);
var downloader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader();
            var download = downloader.createDownload(uri, file);

download.startAsync().then(function () {
   console.log("FOOO DONE !");
}, function(error) {
   console.log("Error while downloading file ", error);
});
```

The contentURL and the file are valid and the files are generated as well. But the download is not starting at all, the file, which was created has just the size of 0kb.

And also no error and success is printed.

What could be wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the exact same code; what fixed it for me is changing the name of the package name (in the package.appxmanifest file) and/or the build number. For some reason I have to do this procedure every day since the downloads don't seem to work when i boot the pc.
I came to the conclusion that it's either a hardware problem or a Visual Studio issue, the code works just fine (once it starts working).